# Array Range how to use with a for loop?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, for-loop

So I'm trying to make a range.  Then make this array a range of 1,2,3,4.  It will use the numbers 1-4., but I would like to shuffle those numbers for example:2,4,1,3.  I'm getting stuck on the array range so far in php.

```
$range = range(1, 4)
$numbers = array($range);
$totalElements = count( $numbers );

for ( $i=0; $i < $totalElements; $i++ ) {
echo $numbers[$i];
if ( $i < $totalElements -1 ) echo ", ";
```

Comment: `$range=range(1,4); shuffle($range); echo implode(',', $range);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
$numbers = range(1, 4);
shuffle($numbers);
foreach ($numbers as $number) {
    echo "$number ";
}
```

Comment: Foreach - makes sense.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

try this function

```
$var  = [1,2,3,4];
    shuffle($var);
print_r($var);
```

sorry.... forgot to allocate it to a variable

Comment: shuffle is "by reference", and returns a boolean true/false for suuccess//failure; so this won't work

Comment: The shuffle method uses a pass-by-reference. So yes, you would need to allocate it first, then use it accordingly